# Branching Process Expected Value

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

> Let $X_0, X_1, ...$ be a branching process with offspring distribution mean $\mu$. Let $Y_n = \frac{X_n}{\mu^n}, n \ne 0$. Show $E[Y_{n+1} | Y_n] = Y_n$

My attempt:

$E[Y_n] = E[\frac{X_n}{\mu^n}] = \frac{1}{\mu^n}E[X_n] = \frac{1}{\mu^n}\mu^n = 1$

But I'm not sure how to continue

Comment: What is the random variable $Z_n$?

Comment: @user375366 sorry it should be $X_n$

Comment: You should try to calculate $E[Y_{n}|Y_{n-1}]$, not $E[Y_n]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z_i$ denote the number of offspring coming from the $i^{\text{th}}$ member.

$
\begin{align*}
E(Y_{n+1}\mid Y_n)&=E(\frac{X_{n+1}}{\mu^{n+1}}\mid\frac{X_n}{\mu^n}) \\
&=\frac{1}{\mu^{n+1}}E(X_{n+1}\mid X_n) \\
&=\frac{1}{\mu^{n+1}}E(\sum_{i=1}^{X_n}Z_i\mid X_n) \\
&=\frac{1}{\mu^{n+1}}X_n\mu \\
&=\frac{X_n}{\mu^n} \\
&=Y_n.
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Why did you compute $E(Y_n | Y_{n-1})$ instead of $E(Y_{n+1} | Y_n)$?

Comment: @user2980566 Because I misread the question.